# How to set target MDS in EAR file with Oracle ADF

Tags: repository, metadata, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I want to enable user customization at run time with Oracle ADF. With JDeveloper, if I deploy my application directly to the server, a window permits me to choose a repository previously registered on my Enterprise Manager, as depicted in following image:

[image: MDS choice]

In this way my application works great. Now I would to deploy to EAR file (in order to save a copy of my release) but I don't know how to target MDS repository. On the web I've found that maybe the adf-config.xml file has to be modify, but in which way?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this blog entry, which explains how to do it. Apparently this information needs to be provided upon EAR file deployment

http://andrejusb.blogspot.de/2011/05/target-mds-repository-for-adf.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've just seen that post, but I don't know how to write the script mentioned there.